# Open layers how to add map markers on Tile layer

Tags: openlayers

I need to show a map marker in an `OpenLayer` map.
I have more layers. This is how one layer looks like in code:

```
 cite:geo_borneFiltered":
            var userId = $("#loggedInUserId").val();

            layers.push(
                new ol.layer.Tile({
                    title: overlays[i].Item2,
                    type: 'overlay',
                    preload: Infinity,
                    visible: false,
                    layer: overlays[i].Item1,
                    source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
                        crossOrigin: 'anonymous',
                        url: GeoServer + "/geoserver/gwc/service/",
                        params: { 'LAYERS': overlays[i].Item1, 'VERSION': '1.1.1', 'service': 'wms', 'tiled': true, viewparams: 'UserId:' + userId },
                        serverType: 'geoserver'
                    })
                })
            );
            break;
        case
```

Every solution that I found was for `ol.layer.Vector`, for example: https://jsfiddle.net/jonataswalker/ckfd9d1L/ 
I have `Tile` layers.
Can you please advise if I can use the same solution as it is for `Vector` layers?

Answer (score 0):

The approach is to use a Vector layer for your icons, and a Tile layer for your maps. Add the Tile layer first, then the Vector layer. This will put the Vector layer on top and it is transparent so it will look like the icons are on the map tiles. OpenLayers will take care of ensuring both layers pan and zoom together.

For an example showing a really similar approach to the fiddle you link, but working with a Tile layer underneath, have a look at this SO question that I answered a while ago:

[OpenLayers onmousedown load image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35826118/openlayers-onmousedown-load-image)

For more precise control of layer ordering, have a look at z-index:

https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/layer-z-index.html

Comment: Thanks. Here is a more detailed version of my question.  https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/269957/map-markers-for-openlayer-map-tiled-layers  Can you please take a look?  I can do this (put the map marker )after the filtering is done? Any advise is appreciated.

Comment: Glad that was useful, but rather than leave this question hanging, we should either close this question in favour of your more detailed one on GIS, or mark this question resolved, or close your GIS question and bring the detail over here so that it can be answered properly. Any preference?